# A way to dynamically move userLocation while testing/showcasing iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, ios13

I know of the GPX files, and I am using them, but i find them a hassle both to create and use, and I wanted to freely move the userLocation around a region and not just teleport it from place to place.

I was thinking of creating a function to move the userLocation by clicking the point you want in the map and teleporting there or moving X meters in the click's direction, the problem is that userLocation is get only.

I have to hand in this app and it must be functional with userLocation implemented, so I cannot go around by creating a different annotation and moving that around.

This feature would only be used to showcase the app without needing to actually walk around campus and while testing.

Does anyone have any workaround to move userLocation around without needing GPX files?

I have mapped all locations I want to "walk" to in GPX files, as seen in the image bellow, but I don't want to be "teleported" there as the debug menu does.

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like? You likely won't be able to fake the device's location in the way you described, but you might be able to just pass in mocked data/coordinates.

Comment: @ZGski I followed [this tutorial](https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/swift-programming/mapkit-tutorial) for implementing MapKit. Other than that, I just fetch userLocation to check if the user is near any annotations I've put in place around campus (it's a treasure hunt). I do this with `guard let userLocation = mapView.userLocation.location`, then I get the distance in CLLocationDistance with `userLocation.distance(from: )`.

Comment: It's probably possible to abstract the logic of _"user is near any annotations"_ into a method that takes in coordinates. When the device's location is updated, pass its coordinates into this new method. If you're testing/showing functionality, simply pass in fake data.

Comment: Wasn’t it possible to select a simulated walk or drive around Apple’s HQ? Haven’t checked recently but pretty sure this was an option.

Comment: @Magnas I think you just lead me in a correct direction! I didn't think of using the words "simulated walk" or drive while researching, and now I'm getting a lot of new results that could solve my problem! I'll update my question with an answer if I find one that works! Thank you ˆˆ

Answer (score 2):

Within the simulator, you can test what the location changes.  From the menu, select `Debug` -> `Location`.  From there, you should have multiple options to choose from. "City Run," "City Bicycle Ride" or "Freeway Drive" are all options that will continue to update and move throughout the simulation.

Comment: You mean [this](https://ibb.co/PNF8h0z) menu? I have only the same GPX files I created, and no options to simulate a drive/walk...